# Log4j RollingFileAppender not working as expected in IBM Portal Server

Tags: java, logging, log4j, websphere-8, websphere-portal

I'm facing strange issue with log4j when deployed in IBM WebSphere Portal Server. Its working pretty well when tested as standalone application link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306986/log4j-rollingfileappender-not-working-as-expected).

Its pretty straight forward RollingFileAppender xml configuraion file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration debug="true"
             xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>
  <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">

  <param name="append" value="true"/>
  <param name="file" value="E:/logs/Mylog.log"/>
  <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB"/>
  <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>

  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
 </layout>
```

```
 <root>
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
   <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
 </root>
```

All I needed is when the log size Mylog.log exceeds 10MB, then it has to create Mylog.1.log, Mylog.2.log, Mylog.3.log and so on.. where as its creating Mylog.1.log, after some time Mylog.2.log will be created and Mylog.1.log will be deleted automatically (when Mylog.3.log would have been created then Mylog.1.log, Mylog.2.log would have been deleted).

Am I doing something wrong, As its enterprise web application, log4j-config.xml will be at business layer and on top of those multiple web applications will be accessing it using singleton factory pattern(One instance of log for all web application modules).

Tried many ways, but in vain, any help is highly appreciable. Thanks.